# In Hbase, what is the difference in scanning between ResultScanner and initTableMapperJob

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I hope someone can tell me what the difference between these two API calls are.  I'm getting weird results between the two of them.  This is happening for hbase-client/hbase-server version 1.0.1 and 1.2.0-cdh5.7.2.

First off, my rowkeys are in the format hash_name_timestamp
e.g. 100_servername_1234567890.  The hbase table has a TTL of 30 days so things older than 30 days should disappear after compaction.

The following is code for using ResultScanner.  It doesn't use MapReduce so it takes a very long time to complete.  I can't run my job this way because it takes too long.  However, for debugging purposes, I don't have any problems with this method.  It lists all keys for the specified time range, which look valid to me since all the timestamps of the returned keys are within the past 30 days and within the specified time range:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("raw_data"), Bytes.toBytes(fileType));
scan.setCaching(500);
scan.setCacheBlocks(false);
scan.setTimeRange(start, end);

Connection fConnection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
Table table = fConnection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result = scanner.next()) {
   System.out.println("Found row: " + Bytes.toString(result.getRow()));
}
```

The follow code doesn't work but it uses MapReduce, which runs way faster than using the ResultScanner way, since it divides things up into 1200 maps.  The problem is I'm getting rowkeys that should have disappeared due to TTL expiring:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("raw_data"), Bytes.toBytes(fileType));
scan.setCaching(500);
scan.setCacheBlocks(false);
scan.setTimeRange(start, end);
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(tableName, scan, MTTRMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, job);
```

Here is the error that I get, which eventually kills the whole MR job later because over 25% of the mappers failed.

> Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException:
>   Failed after attempts=36, exceptions: Wed Jun 28 13:46:57 PDT 2017,
>   null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=120000,
>   callDuration=120301: row '65_app129041.iad1.mydomain.com_1476641940'
>   on table 'server_based_data' at region=server_based_data

I'll try to study the code for the hbase-client and hbase-server jars but hopefully someone will know offhand what the difference between the methods are and what is causing the initTableMapperJob call to fail.

EDIT: Here is the description of the table that I'm using:

```
describe 'server_based_data'
Table server_based_data is ENABLED                                              
server_based_data                                                               
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION                                                     
{NAME => 'raw_data', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLIC
ATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY', MIN_VERSIONS => '0
', TTL => '2592000 SECONDS (30 DAYS)', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE 
=> '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}                         
1 row(s) in 0.5180 seconds
```

Here is my mapper code:

```
public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable rowkey, Result columns, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    startMS = conf.getLong("startTime", 0);
    endMS = conf.getLong("endTime", 1);
    System.out.println(startMS);
    System.out.println(endMS);

    // extract the ci as the key from the rowkey
    String pattern = "\\d*_(\\S*)_(\\d{10})";
    String ciname = null;
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    String strRowKey = Bytes.toString(rowkey.get());
    // check the time here to see if we count it or not in the counts

    Matcher m = r.matcher(strRowKey);
    long ts = 0;

    if (m.find()) {
        ts = Long.valueOf(m.group(2)).longValue();
        ciname = m.group(1);
        if ((ts >= startMS) && (ts <= endMS)) {
            context.write(new Text(ciname), ONE);           
        }           
    }       
}
```

I still think there's something with the initTableMapperJob method because the error I posted above shows a timestamp of a row that should have expired from the TTL of the table but for some reason, initTableMapperJob still finds it and tries to look for it but times out, whereas the ResultScanner doesn't see it for some reason.

Comment: Could you please provide more details regarding you map reduce job and describe Hbase table. If you are interested I can suggest you approach with Spark on Hbase.

Comment: @gorros, thanks for your help.  Yes, if you have a suggestion with spark, I'll listen.  Hopefully it's easy to implement and I'm smart enough to understand you.  I've also updated the question with some more details as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions I would like to make.

1. Take a look at [Spark on HBase examples](https://github.com/tmalaska/SparkOnHBase/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/hbasecontext/HBaseDistributedScanExample.scala), particularly how to perform a scan with Spark. It is written in Scala but you may achieve same in Java. Even in that case, it will be much concise than MapReduce code.
2. If you need only row keys, add corresponding filters such as [FirstKeyOnlyFilter](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#individualfiltersyntax). This will reduce the amount of unnecessary data retrieved from HBase.

I am not sure what caused the strange behavior of `initTableMapperJob`. But I hope above suggestion will be useful.